# The type GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 is deprecated

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am using following code to connect to gremlin (JanusGraph) server and execute addV in transaction. My code works fine and it add Vertex properly, but code shows following warnings:
***"The type GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 is deprecated"*** &
***The method getInstance() from the type JanusGraphIoRegistry is deprecated***

So would like to know how can i get these warning resolved.
Please find my code below:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Result;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.Serializers;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.binary.GraphBinaryIo;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoMapper;
import org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry;

public class JanusSessiionConnector {

    final static GryoMapper.Builder builder = GryoMapper.build().
            addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.getInstance());
    final static GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 serializer = new GryoMessageSerializerV3d0(builder);
    final static GraphBinaryIo serializer2 = new GraphBinaryIo();
    
    final static Cluster cluster = Cluster.build().addContactPoint("localhost").port(8182)
            .serializer(serializer)
            .maxInProcessPerConnection(32).maxSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(32).maxContentLength(1000000)
            .maxWaitForConnection(10).minConnectionPoolSize(1).maxConnectionPoolSize(1).create();

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Welcome to janus connector");
        String sessionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Client sessionClient = cluster.connect(sessionId);

        try {
            sessionClient.submit("graph.tx().open()");
            sessionClient.submit("g.addV('Person').property('Name', 'Justin').next()");
            sessionClient.submit("graph.tx().commit()");
            List<Result> rs = sessionClient.submit("g.V().count()").all().join();
            System.out.println("Result size is "+rs.size());
            System.out.println(rs.get(0).getString());
            System.out.println("5");
            sessionClient.closeAsync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sessionClient != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Connection closed ");
                cluster.close();
            }
        }
        }
}
```

Thanks,
Atul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning message is just letting you know that features you are using have been deprecated. If you look at the TinkerPop [javadoc](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/ser/GryoMessageSerializerV3d0.html) you can see how to resolve this problem - simply, prefer `GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1` to Gryo. You can often find helpful information for these sorts of things in the TinkerPop [Upgrade Documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/upgrade/#_deprecate_gryo_in_gremlin_server). That said, you are using JanusGraph and depending on the version you are using I'm not sure that their `IoRegistry` implementation is supporting GraphBinary yet. While their latest code on their `master` branch shows support I don't see that code in a tagged version. It may be best to stay on Gryo a while longer until GraphBinary is fully supported as depending on the Gremlin you write you may hit some serialization problems. The warnings are just warnings - they should not impact your usage.

As for the `JanusGraphIoRegistry` deprecation warning you can get rid of that pretty easily - simply prefer `instance()` rather than `getInstance()` ([source code](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/v0.5.3/janusgraph-driver/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/graphdb/tinkerpop/JanusGraphIoRegistry.java#L40-L42)).